# CSS Background to stretch to window bottom?

Tags: css, background, stretch

I am helping to redesign a website [www.liveatsheastadium.com/test](http://liveatsheastadium.com/test)

I am trying to figure out a way to get the transparent background (using the background:rgba property) to stretch the entire height of the page regardless of resolution.

I have tried setting the container, html and body height to 100% and using the background:cover property.

Any ideas on how to get the background to extend to the bottom of the page regardless of broswer window size?

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="mainContent">
        <ul id="nav">
                        <li><img src="images/nav/archives.jpg" /><a href="archives.html" title="archives">archives</a></li>
                        <li><img src="images/nav/calendar.jpg" /><a href="calendar.html" title="calendar">calendar</a></li>
                        <li><img src="images/nav/studio.jpg" /><a href="studio.html" title="studio" >studio</a></li>
                        <li><img src="images/nav/blog.jpg" /><a href="http://sheastadiumbk.blogspot.com/" title="blog">blog</a></li>
                        <li><img src="images/nav/contact.jpg" /><a href="contact.html" title="contact" >contact</a></li>
                    </ul>


        <div class="blogPost ">
            <h2><a href="#">The Lebonese, Tits, and The Chinese at Shea tonight</a></h2>
            <p class="date">posted on 7.15.11</p>
            <h3>Face Melting, coke snorting good times</h3>
            <div class="blogBody">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>   
                <p>Borem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p> 
            </div><!--END BLOGBODY-->
            <div class="meta">
                <ul>
                        <li><a href="http://google.com ">read more...</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Tweet This</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">re-post on facebook</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!--end META-->
        </div><!--END BLOGPOST-->
    </div><!--END MAIN CONTENT-->


    <div id="aside">
        <ul id="socialIcons">
                <li><a href="http//twitter.com"><img src="images/icons/facebook.png" alt=""/></a></li>
                <li><a href="http//facebook.com"><img src="images/icons/twitter.png" alt=""/></a></li>
                <li><a href="subscribeToMailingList"><img src="images/icons/rss.png" alt=""/></a></li>
            </ul>
        <div id="tabs">
        <div id="latest">
            <h2>Latest</h2> 
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">liturgy - 7.04.11</a></li>
                <li><a href="">sightings - 7.04.11 (full set)</a></li>
                <li><a href="">liturgy - 7.04.11</a></li>
                <li><a href="">sightings - 7.04.11 (full set)</a></li>
                <li><a href="">liturgy - 7.04.11</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>  
            <div id="sheaFaves">
                <h2>Shea Faves</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">future islands - 7.4.10</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Small Black - 10.15.10</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">future islands - 7.4.10</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Small Black - 10.15.10</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">future islands - 7.4.10</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div><!--END TABS-->
            <div id="featuredBand">
                <h2>Featured Band:</h2>
                <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100" />
                <h3><a href="">The Chinese</a></h3>
                <p>The Chinese are a Brooklyn Based band whose style mixes blah blah blah blah blah.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="guestPlaylist">
                <h2>Guest Playlist</h2>
                <object height="81" width="100%"> <param name="movie" value="http://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F19242183&amp;show_comments=false&amp;auto_play=false&amp;color=000000"></param> <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param> <param name="wmode" value="window"></param><embed wmode="window" allowscriptaccess="always" height="81" src="http://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F19242183&amp;show_comments=false&amp;auto_play=false&amp;color=000000" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%"></embed> </object>   <span><a href="http://soundcloud.com/shlohmo/marvins-room-shlohmos-thru-tha">Marvin's Room (Shlohmo's thru tha floor remix) - Drake</a> by <a href="http://soundcloud.com/shlohmo">shlohmo</a></span>
            </div>
        </div><!--END ASIDE-->
    </div><!--END CONTAINER-->
```

And the CSS

```
    body {
    background: #000 url('../images/bg-light.jpg') no-repeat top left fixed;
}

    #container {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:1080px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}


    #nav {
    padding:15px 0px;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

    #nav li {
    text-align:center;
    width:110px;
    float:left;
}

    #nav img {
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
}

    #nav a {
    font-family:'Oswald', arial, sans-serif;
    margin-top:5px;
    display:block;
    font-size:.80em;
    font-weight:500;
    letter-spacing: .3em;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}

    #nav a:hover {
    color:#fff;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #bebebe;
}


    #socialIcons li {
    display:inline;

    margin-right:15px;
}

#socialIcons img {
    width:50px;
}

#mainContent {
    width:70%;
    float:left;
}

#aside {
    overflow:hidden;
    width:30%;
    float:right;
}

#tabs, #guestPlaylist, #featuredBand {
    margin-bottom:50px;
    padding-right:15px;
}

#tabs {
    margin-top:115px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', arial, sans-serif;
}

#latest, #sheaFaves {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
}

#aside h2 {
    border-bottom:1px dotted #fff;
    color:#fff;
    letter-spacing:.1em;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

#latest li a, #sheaFaves li a {
    font-size:.75em;
}

#tabs-1 li, #tabs-2 li {
    letter-spacing:.1em;
    font-size:.65em;
    line-height:1.3em;
}

#featuredBand {
    margin-top:260px;
    clear:both;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#featuredBand h2 {
    margin-bottom:15px;
}
#featuredBand img {
    float:left;
    width:40%;
    margin-right:10px;
}

#featuredBand h3 {
    margin-bottom:5px;
}

#featuredBand p {
    line-height:1.2em;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add these rules:

```
body, html{
    height:100%;
    margn:0;
    padding:0;
}

#container{
    min-height:100%;
}
```

However, `min-height` isn't fully supported in all browsers. If you use `height` instead it will cause problems if the content in container is higher than the page. To work around this, you could create a 100% x 100% div as a duplicate of body, give it a background image that is your transparent overlay, and set its `overflow` to `auto`, so it behaves like a second body tag.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id='body2'>
        //container
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background:_image_;
}

#body2{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:auto;
    background:url(transparent.png) center top repeat-y;
}
```

transparent.png would be containerWidth x 1px filled with the rgba color you wanted as the container background.

Comment: Thank you, the first part worked. The second part (using a repeating img slice) may be necessary. What broswers don't support min-height?

Comment: The unsupported browsers are all old ones. Full details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/min-height#Browser_compatibility

Comment: however redundant it seems it's the only solution... The first approach breaks if the content is longer than the page and html has background that is used for page margins - this background begins right after the fold. And if you set "min-height: 100%" everywhere it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Viewport height works for modern browsers.

Try this:
height:100vh;

Here's the support(ie11+):
https://caniuse.com/#search=vh