# Stretch image to bottom of screen css

Tags: html, css

I wish to have an image (`img` tag not background to a `div`) which stretches full width and stretches to the bottom of the page (without stretching to the top).

I have tried the solution described here: [CSS Background to stretch to window bottom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780808/css-background-to-stretch-to-window-bottom)

but I am only getting it to stretch 100% in relation to the page, and creating a scrollbar and going under the page. I tried various variations (with `min-height` instead of `height` and I either get the image back to just full width (without stretching height to the bottom) or it stretches beyond the screen.

I have prepared a small JSFiddle of what CSS and HTML I have so far, although the effect might not be so visible.

http://jsfiddle.net/Sk55Z/

What am I missing?

Comment: what's the jsfiddle link?

Comment: sorry forgot to save before I copied and pasted the URL, updated the link

Comment: Please provide a working link to your code on jsfillde.net or a sample code with your post. The link you provided goes to a blank jsfiddle project sheet. Thanks I retract my statement. Got it.

Comment: the big image in your fiddle is a background image not an img tag. What is it you want to achieve? Fix image position to bottom? thats easy. Pls explain better what you are trieng to do.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand, what you're trying to achieve here, something like this? -> http://jsfiddle.net/Sk55Z/1/

Comment: @GNi33 Yes, thats the idea. But thats not quite right. If you resize the divider of the screen you'll see scrollbars rather than just keeping to the bottom of the screen. I tried it on a separate HTML file on chrome and it is still leaving the bottom part empty and not expanding to fill it :(

Comment: @user1721135 No its not. The background is just the small logo to demonstrate that there is something I do not wish to cover. The big image is an <img> tag. ` <img id="frontimg" src="http://www.deshow.net/d/file/travel/2009-06/brazil-landscape-580-2.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"/>`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Sk55Z/1/ seems to work though? I dont see any scroll bars on window resize.

Comment: Yesterday I did get the scrollbars when I tried it for some reason, don't know if I resized the window or did something that confused JSFiddle. Now I tried it again, and the problem I have is that when I resize the image goes behind the Logo. I want it to stay for within a 100px `margin-top` and not go behind the logo.

Answer (score 1):

I would look into jQuery Backstretch to make it cross browser. You can also use conditional html statements to rely on background cover to maintain a correct aspect ratio.

```
.iebg {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; /* here is where you specify how low you want the image to start */
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Throw that class on an image tag.

And here is an example with just an image tag:

http://jsfiddle.net/Sk55Z/2/

Comment: Whats new in your example? I can't see it working. It is still creating scrollbars and bleeding beyond the bottom of the frame.

Comment: I tried it with your `.iebg` example. However part of the image is not visible now. If I put `top: 100px`, then the image is just moved down (not squashed) and I loose 100px from the bottom.