# why in background size the height is not working?

Tags: css, background-size

`background-size` the height property is not working why?

```css
body{
    background-image: url("images/1.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-position: 50px 50px;   
}
```

Comment: what if you add min-height:100% to html element?

Comment: Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780808/css-background-to-stretch-to-window-bottom

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
body{
  background-image: url('images/1.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-width: 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: 50px 50px;
}
```

Maybe it'll fix the problem (: